# What does GARP in revealed preferences mean and how to regocnize it graphically?

Tags: consumer-theory, preferences

I have a froblem understanding GARP  in revealed preferences. I know what WARP means, and that SARP adds transivity such that it allows for indirect preferences, but what about GARP?

How can you recognize it graphically?